# How do you set search path to schema in Postgresql using ODBC in MS Access?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to do what on the surface seems pretty simple.  I am trying to export a table from MS Access to a Postgresql database using the ODBC driver connection.

If you use the default settings for the driver, the location for a table is going to be in the "public" schema.  I have this set to read-only for security reasons.  I thus receive this error when I try to run the export:

[image: Public Schema permission error]

Upon seeing the error, I realized my mistake, that I didn't want this table to be created in that schema anyway.  The question then became, how to specify a particular schema for export using ODBC?

After much searching, I found this answer about setting the search path:
[image: Search Path]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/1388679

I then tried to add that in as a `Connection Setting` on the advanced options of the MS Access export windows.
[image: Connection Settings]

When I do this, and try to run it, I receive the following error:
[image: Error flush socket buffer]

Based on everything I have read, this seems like it should be working.  The only thing I can think of is that I have the syntax incorrect for the `connection setting`.  If it is not that, then do I need to actually follow the answer I referenced, and set the default schema every time I want to do an export like this?

I have seen a couple of questions discussing this, but they simple reference setting the `search_path`, but that is all.  There is no discussion of syntax.

Comment: Take a look at the PostgreSQL log files and see if there's any error after your ODBC connection attempt. You might need a semicolon at the end of the connect setting? Or maybe they're meant to be passed in `key=value` form not as `SET` statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem boiled down, as I thought, to a syntax error.  Of course, the error thrown by MS Access doesn't say anything about that, but it is.

Here is a capture of the string that works.  Please note the semicolon `;` at the end of the `SET search_path` string.

[image: Connection Options - Correct String]